# How I get the parentnode attribute name if I have the attribute name of the child node?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable, nodes

hi  i want to get the up node from a xml. For example here a xml structure...

```
<feature name="mod1">
  <user name="user1"></user>
  <user name="user2"></user>
  <user name="user3"></user>
</feature>
```

i have in my application the username and i want than the node feature name attribute.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));

            XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);

            int counter = 0; 
            foreach (XElement user in doc.Descendants("USER"))
            {
                try
                {
                    row = tb.NewRow();
                    row["ID"] = counter++;
                    row["Name"] = user.Attribute("NAME").Value;
                    row["Host"] = user.Attribute("HOST").Value;
                    row["Used_Licenses"] = user.Attribute("USED_LICENSES").Value;
                    row["Checkout_Time"] = user.Attribute("CHECKOUT_TIME").Value;


                   row["Modul"] = user.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value; //don't work :(

                    tb.Rows.Add(row); 
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

            }
```

Comment: Please provide the entire xml with closing tag.

Comment: @Tarasov what are the `>` after each USER tag ?

Comment: By the way, my answer (with upper case : `user.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value`) works perfectly with your sample...

Comment: i don't know but the xml i get from a other programm ...so i must work with them :/

Comment: i get with this xml all users and the features but i don't know how i get the feature name if i have the user name :D :(

Comment: Not working means - What is this line of code `user.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value;` returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to get it by

```
user.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value;
```

this Works with :

```
<LM-X STAT_VERSION="3.32">
<LICENSE_PATH >
<FEATURE NAME="GlobalZoneEU" >
<USER NAME="SYSTEM" HOST="LRV171" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" SHARE_CUSTOM="hweuser:172.16.11.115"/>
<USER NAME="pbsadmin" HOST="SERV11" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="720" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:44" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:44" SHARE_CUSTOM="pbsadmin:LWSERV171:1592_40960072_1356792762_826820"/>
</FEATURE>
</LICENSE_PATH>
</LM-X>
```

**EDIT**

Get the feature name by user name :

```
var featureNames = xDoc.Descendants("USER")
                        .Where(x => x.Attribute("NAME").Value == <your input>)
                        .Select(x => x.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value);

var firstFeatureName = featureNames.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an object instance. :(

Comment: @Tarasov. The sample xml doesn't correspond to your code (Many Null Ref Exception if I try YOUR code with YOUR xml). Give a real sample, or check for Attribute case (It might be "NAME")

Comment: @Tarasov : With closing TAGS please.

Comment: Are you sure that `Row["Modul"]` exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the attributes are case sensitive.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(\\File Path);

        XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (XElement user in doc.Descendants("USER"))
        {
            try
            {
                string node = user.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value; //Working - Returning 'GlobalZoneEU'
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: mhh is use not a pth to a xml i use a xml string that i create in my application but the content is the same.

Comment: i don't understand why it works by you and not by me :D your example is right but it don't work :/

Comment: What is the error? What is this line of code `user.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value;` returning?

Comment: Can you please provide xml string?

Comment: ok it works but with user.Parent.Parent.Attribute("NAME").Value; :D:D

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you.

```
        string xml = "<feature name=\"mod1\">";
        xml += "<user name=\"user1\"> </user>";
        xml += "<user name=\"user2\"> </user> ";
        xml += "<user name=\"user3\"></user>";
        xml += "</feature>";

        XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

        XDocument mydoc = XDocument.Parse(xdoc.OuterXml);

        var result = mydoc.Elements("feature").Where(parent =>
                          parent.Elements("user").Any(child =>   
                          child.Attribute("name").Value == "user2"));
```

and don't forget to include 
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;